# KrakenD Body Manipulation not manipulating

Tags: krakend

I am under the impression that KrakenD Body manipulation and generation (https://www.krakend.io/docs/enterprise/backends/body-generator/) of the body to the new request. Basically

> the body generator modifier allows you to craft the body you send to a
> backend through templates, and enables injecting other values from the
> user request such as the original body, headers, querystrings or URL
> parameters.

I am creating a configuration file that defines:

```
 {
  "$schema": "https://www.krakend.io/schema/v3.json",
  "version": 3,
  "debug_endpoint": true,
   "endpoints": [
        {
            "endpoint": "/bodygenerator/{id}",
            "method": "GET",
            "input_headers": [ "Content-Type" ],
            "backend": [
                {
                    "url_pattern": "/anything/{id}",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "encoding": "json",
                    "extra_config": {
                        "modifier/body-generator": {
                            "path": "./body.json.tmpl",
                            "content_type": "application/json",
                            "debug": true
                        }
                    },
                    "host": [ "http://httpbin.org/" ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
  "port": 8010
}
```

with the template being

```
{
  "id": "{{ .req_params.Id }}",
  "message": "User said {{ .req_body.text }}"
}
```

I would expect, that upon calling http://krakenUrL/bodygenerator/someID the result to be as in the template when I call the API Gateway created by KrakenD, but I am getting a forwarder from the get, to a POST but without a body:

```
{
    "args": {},
    "data": "",
    "files": {},
    "form": {},
    "headers": {
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
        "Content-Length": "0",
        "Host": "httpbin.org",
        "User-Agent": "KrakenD Version 2.2.1",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6422d748-3e1c5def04f1fb5b56794eab",
        "X-Forwarded-Host": "api.pxou.com:8010"
    },
    "json": null,
    "method": "POST",
    "origin": "******",
    "url": "http://krakenD:8010/anything/100"
}
```

Tested with

1. KrakenD Version: 2.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this feature is not available in the Community Edition (https://www.krakend.io/features/).